# R Shiny- Formatting on top of formatting

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to `R` and stumbled upon `Shiny in R`. I am trying to format a column that is a currency and I also want to format it to two decimal points.

So a piece of my code is:

```
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(  
  DT::datatable(table(), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching=FALSE))%>% 
  formatCurrency(c(4,6,7), currency = "$", interval = 0, mark = ",") %>% formatRound(c(4,6,7), digits=2)
```

but the *digits do not get formatted* in this command. The dummy columns in this case are 4,6,7 which all are currencies. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `formatCurrency` is probably a string, so you cannot feed it to `formatRound`. In fact you can specify digits in `formatCurrency` itself.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the response. When I run the app, I am able to sort out the column by largest to least (vice versa), so I do not know if the class is  a string. Do you happen to know how I can call the digits within  formatCurrency? 
When I call digits within formatCurrency, I get  'Error: unused argument (digits=2)'

Comment: You probably need a newer version of DT. I have `DT_0.1.46` and it works here.

Comment: Hi
Do you happen to know where I can find the latest tar.gz file for this package? I am unable to 'check for package update' on R studio.

Comment: I installed the github version https://github.com/rstudio/DT `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the info, all went well.